# Como popular select de acordo com dados de outro select no Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Gostaria de fazer um select dinâmico, de forma que quando eu escolher o estado, carregue as cidades daquele estado no outro select.

Cidade e estado estão em tabelas diferentes, mas possuem chave estrangeira, de modo que quando eu cadastro uma cidade, automaticamente é identifico a qual estado ela pertence.

Já foi feita relação de belong to de cidade para estado e de has many de estado para cidade.

O select no blade está assim:

```
  <div class="row gy-3">
            <div class="col-6">
                <label class="form-label">Estado: </label>
                <select class="form-select form-select-md" name="unifed" class="form-control" id="uf_id">
                    <option selected>Selecione</option>
                    @foreach($ufs as $uf)
                        <option value="{{ $uf['id'] }}"> {{ $uf['sigla'] }} </option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>

      
            <div class="col-6">
                <label class="form-label">Cidade: </label>
                <select class="form-select form-select-md" name="cidade" class="form-control" id="cidade_id">
                    <option selected>Selecione</option>
                    @foreach($cidades as $cidade)
                        <option value="{{ $cidade['id'] }}"> {{ $cidade['nome'] }}  </option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
```

O que eu preciso alterar? Pois, no select da cidade está aparecendo todas as cidades.

Já tentei varias soluções mas nenhuma funcionou.

Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço desde já. Isso é realmente muito importante.

Answer (score 0):

Eu utilizo muito o Jquery e o Ajax para fazer este tipo de serviço, não te garanto ser a melhor solução, possivelmente você pode manipular essas informações no próprio javascript, sem necessariamente fazer requisição no banco a cada evento novo, mas caso queira utilizar vou te mandar o passo a passo como eu fiz numa situação parecida comigo.

Primeiramente você deve fazer uma rota no web.php para fazer a requisição das cidades.

```
    Route::post('/encontrar-cidade', 'CityController@findCity');
```

Aqui faremos a função que vai ser realizada no controller para achar as cidades do estado selecionado, neste caso ele vai retornar as cidades com o ID igual do estado que será enviado pelo ajax, eu nomeei como "estado_id", e a chave estrangeira é o ID que você colocou na database.

```
public function findCity(Request $request) {
    $cities = SeuModelDeCidade::all();
    return $cities->where('chave_estrangeira_estado_id', '=', $request['estado_id']);
}
```

A view ficou assim:

```
<div class="col-6">
    <label class="form-label">Estado: </label>
    <select data-url="{{ url('/econtrar-cidade') }}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" onchange="changeCity(this)" name="unifed" id="uf_id">
        <option selected>Selecione</option>
        @foreach($ufs as $uf)
            <option value="{{ $uf['id'] }}"> {{ $uf['sigla'] }} </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
    <label class="form-label">Cidade: </label>
    <select class="form-select form-select-md" name="cidade" class="form-control" id="cidade_id">
        <option selected>Selecione</option>
    </select>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.16/webfont.js"></script>
<script>
function changeCity(response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(response).data('url'),
        type: 'post',
        data: {_method: 'post', _token: $(response).data('token'), state_id: response.value},
        success: function(res) {
            $("#cidade_id").empty();
            $.each( res, function(a, b) {
                $('#cidade_id').append($('<option>', {value: b['id'], text: b['nome']}));
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('error');
        },
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigada! Amigo, eu entendi o código e a sua lógica sendo que agora a lista de cidades esta vazia. Independente de eu escolher um estado, a lista de cidades não esta puxando as cidades do banco. O public function findcity eu coloquei no Controller de Cidade. Esta correto?

Comment: Vitória, o controller que você colocar é indiferente, porque a rota vai redirecionar para o controller que você indicou, e este vai executar a função, então não acredito que seja este o problema. O erro pode estar em muitos locais, eu teria que ter mais informações para te dizer o motivo do erro. Primeiramente, ele está executando a function changeCity? (dá um console.log na função para verificar). Se sim, ele está caindo na função findCity do controller? (você pode utilizar o dd() do php para descobrir). E me diga o erro que está acontecendo

Comment: faltou um "n" no select, eu escrevi "econtrar-cidade" ao invés de "encontrar-cidade", talvez o erro seja este.